# Building a for loop around exsisting loop, to replace user input

Tags: bash, shell-script, ffmpeg

I basicly have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Asks For filname and Word
echo 'Which word are you looking for?'
read word
echo 'What's the name of the file?'
read fileName


#Searches word and parses the line-numbers 
wordOut=$(grep -i -n -w $word $fileName.srt |cut -f1 -d:)

#Sets all outputs to diffrent line numbers and saves a temp file
for word in $wordOut
do
    echo $word
done >file.tmp

#Parses lines to array, removes temp file
mapfile -t arr <file.tmp
rm file.tmp

#Declares variable for the number of array entries (not used anywhere atm)
ln=${#arr[@]}

#Subtract all array entries with one
one=1
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    crc=`expr $i - $one`
    echo $crc
done >two.tmp

#Subtraction result to array2
mapfile -t arr2 <two.tmp
rm two.tmp
echo ${arr2[@]}

#retrieve times
for h in "${arr2[@]}"
do 
    line=$(sed "${h}q;d" $fileName.srt)
    echo $line
done >three.tmp

#replace all commas with decimal points
sed 's/,/./g' three.tmp >four.tmp

#remove temp file 3 and parse 'decimal pointed' to array
rm three.tmp
mapfile -t arr3 <four.tmp
rm four.tmp

echo ${arr3[0]}
echo ${arr3[1]}

# converts HH:MM:SS.sss to fractional seconds
codes2seconds() (
  local hh=${1%%:*}
  local rest=${1#*:}
  local mm=${rest%%:*}
  local ss=${rest#*:}
  printf "%s" $(bc <<< "$hh * 60 * 60 + $mm * 60 + $ss")
)

# converts fractional seconds to HH:MM:SS.sss
seconds2codes() (
  local seconds=$1
  local hh=$(bc <<< "scale=0; $seconds / 3600")
  local remainder=$(bc <<< "$seconds % 3600")
  local mm=$(bc <<< "scale=0; $remainder / 60")
  local ss=$(bc <<< "$remainder % 60")
  printf "%02d:%02d:%06.3f" "$hh" "$mm" "$ss"
)

subtracttimes() (
  local t1sec=$(codes2seconds "$1")
  local t2sec=$(codes2seconds "$2")
  printf "%s" $(bc <<< "$t2sec - $t1sec")
)


for range in "${arr3[@]}"
do  
  mod=$(sed 's/[^0-9]//g' <<< $range)
  duration=$(subtracttimes "${range%% -->*}" "${range##*--> }")
  printf "%s\n" "ffmpeg -i $fileName.mp4 -ss ${range%% -->*} -t $duration -async 1 $word.$mod.$fileName.cut.mp4"


done >final.tmp
sudo chmod 755 final.tmp
./final.tmp
rm final.tmp
```

Which works perfectly fine. What it does: it searches the srt file, which has the same name has the mp4 file for a keyword, then finds the timestamp which matches this keyword, and cuts away the video from the starting point to the end point.

SRT file, for example:

```
**video.srt**
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:04,950
welkom bij eerste toekomst reizen dus

2
00:00:02,639 --> 00:00:05,670
onderdeel aan de achterhoekse toekomst

3
00:00:04,950 --> 00:00:07,290
stoere

4
00:00:05,670 --> 00:00:11,250
mijn heren nu al heel veel dingen
```

So basically if you're looking for the keyword "toekomst", it will output two mp4's, one which originally started at  `00:00:00,000` and ended at `00:00:04,950`, and one which started at `00:00:02,639` and ended at `00:00:05,670`.

I have multiple MP4's in the same directory, all with an corresponding .srt file with the same name as the mp4, which all need to be run through this script. So I want to build a script extensions which looks for all the files with the same names, and runs it through the script.

So I wrote this piece of code to test this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "`dirname "$0"`"
for file in *.srt
do 
fileName="$( basename "$file" .srt)"
echo $fileName
echo $fileName.mp4
echo $fileName.srt

done >temp
```

and it indeed gives the output of all the .mp4 files and .srt files in the directory:

```
h
h.mp4
h.srt
r
r.mp4
r.srt
```

So then I build this for loop around the existing code as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "`dirname "$0"`"
#Asks For filname and Word
echo 'Which word are you looking for?'
read word

for file in *.srt
do 
fileName="$( basename "$file" .srt)"

#Searches word and parses the line-numbers 
wordOut=$(grep -i -n -w $word $fileName.srt |cut -f1 -d:)

#Sets all outputs to diffrent line numbers and saves a temp file
for word in $wordOut
do
    echo $word
done >file.tmp

#Parses lines to array, removes temp file
mapfile -t arr <file.tmp
rm file.tmp

#Declares variable for the number of array entries (not used anywhere atm)
ln=${#arr[@]}

#Subtract all array entries with one
one=1
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    crc=`expr $i - $one`
    echo $crc
done >two.tmp

#Subtraction result to array2
mapfile -t arr2 <two.tmp
rm two.tmp
echo ${arr2[@]}

#retrieve times
for h in "${arr2[@]}"
do 
    line=$(sed "${h}q;d" $fileName.srt)
    echo $line
done >three.tmp

#replace all commas with decimal points
sed 's/,/./g' three.tmp >four.tmp

#remove temp file 3 and parse 'decimal pointed' to array
rm three.tmp
mapfile -t arr3 <four.tmp
rm four.tmp

echo ${arr3[0]}
echo ${arr3[1]}

# converts HH:MM:SS.sss to fractional seconds
codes2seconds() (
  local hh=${1%%:*}
  local rest=${1#*:}
  local mm=${rest%%:*}
  local ss=${rest#*:}
  printf "%s" $(bc <<< "$hh * 60 * 60 + $mm * 60 + $ss")
)

# converts fractional seconds to HH:MM:SS.sss
seconds2codes() (
  local seconds=$1
  local hh=$(bc <<< "scale=0; $seconds / 3600")
  local remainder=$(bc <<< "$seconds % 3600")
  local mm=$(bc <<< "scale=0; $remainder / 60")
  local ss=$(bc <<< "$remainder % 60")
  printf "%02d:%02d:%06.3f" "$hh" "$mm" "$ss"
)

subtracttimes() (
  local t1sec=$(codes2seconds "$1")
  local t2sec=$(codes2seconds "$2")
  printf "%s" $(bc <<< "$t2sec - $t1sec")
)


for range in "${arr3[@]}"
do  
  mod=$(sed 's/[^0-9]//g' <<< $range)
  duration=$(subtracttimes "${range%% -->*}" "${range##*--> }")
  printf "%s\n" "ffmpeg -i $fileName.mp4 -ss ${range%% -->*} -t $duration -async 1 $word.$mod.$fileName.cut.mp4"


done >final.tmp
sudo chmod 755 final.tmp
./final.tmp
rm final.tmp

done
```

and for the first run, with the first file it gives the correct output mp4's but after that it shuffles the variables in some way that I can't get the proper output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it myself by using another script and exporting the variables to the main script, so in the end I've used these two scripts.
**Main script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Welk woord zoek je?'
read word
export word

for file in *.srt
do

fileName="$( basename "$file" .srt)"
export fileName
./actualScript

done
```

**Actual script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
#Asks For filname and Word

#Searches word and parses the line-numbers 
wordOut=$(grep -i -n -w $word $fileName.srt |cut -f1 -d:)

#Sets all outputs to diffrent line numbers and saves a temp file
for word in $wordOut
do
    echo $word
done >file.tmp

#Parses lines to array, removes temp file
mapfile -t arr <file.tmp
rm file.tmp

#Declares variable for the number of array entries (not used anywhere atm)
ln=${#arr[@]}

#Subtract all array entries with one
one=1
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    crc=`expr $i - $one`
    echo $crc
done >two.tmp

#Subtraction result to array2
mapfile -t arr2 <two.tmp
rm two.tmp
echo ${arr2[@]}

#retrieve times
for h in "${arr2[@]}"
do 
    line=$(sed "${h}q;d" $fileName.srt)
    echo $line
done >three.tmp

#replace all commas with decimal points
sed 's/,/./g' three.tmp >four.tmp

#remove temp file 3 and parse 'decimal pointed' to array
rm three.tmp
mapfile -t arr3 <four.tmp
rm four.tmp

echo ${arr3[0]}
echo ${arr3[1]}

# converts HH:MM:SS.sss to fractional seconds
codes2seconds() (
  local hh=${1%%:*}
  local rest=${1#*:}
  local mm=${rest%%:*}
  local ss=${rest#*:}
  printf "%s" $(bc <<< "$hh * 60 * 60 + $mm * 60 + $ss")
)

# converts fractional seconds to HH:MM:SS.sss
seconds2codes() (
  local seconds=$1
  local hh=$(bc <<< "scale=0; $seconds / 3600")
  local remainder=$(bc <<< "$seconds % 3600")
  local mm=$(bc <<< "scale=0; $remainder / 60")
  local ss=$(bc <<< "$remainder % 60")
  printf "%02d:%02d:%06.3f" "$hh" "$mm" "$ss"
)

subtracttimes() (
  local t1sec=$(codes2seconds "$1")
  local t2sec=$(codes2seconds "$2")
  printf "%s" $(bc <<< "$t2sec - $t1sec")
)


for range in "${arr3[@]}"
do  
  mod=$(sed 's/[^0-9]//g' <<< $range)
  duration=$(subtracttimes "${range%% -->*}" "${range##*--> }")
  printf "%s\n" "ffmpeg -i $fileName.mp4 -ss ${range%% -->*} -t $duration -async 1 $word.$mod.$fileName.cut.mp4"


done >final.tmp
sudo chmod 755 final.tmp
./final.tmp
rm final.tmp
```